# Snow Leopard, Homebrew python 2.7, virtualenv, libjpeg and PIL = import error

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

There are a ton of permutations of this question on StackOverflow and the web in general.  I've tried a lot of things and nothing works for me.

Here's my setup.  I'm running OS X 10.6.  I've used Homebrew to install Python 2.7.1:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Mar 12 2011, 16:21:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
```

Note, in Activity Monitor this is reported as a 64-bit process.

First I tried installing libjpeg with Homebrew.  Later I uninstalled it and have been installing it to /usr/local by downloading the source, like so:

```
export CC="/usr/bin/gcc -arch x86_64"
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
```

Then, in my Django virtualenv, I reinstall PIL:

```
export CC="/usr/bin/gcc -arch x86_64"
pip uninstall PIL
pip install --no-install PIL
vi build/PIL/setup.py  # change JPEG_ROOT to libinclude("/usr/local")
pip install PIL
```

And still, it doesn't work:

```
>>> import _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/byp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Users/me/byp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Answer (score 5):

`byp` is your virtualenv?  I just did the same thing, though with the system Python 2.6 and had no problems.  You can install `libjpeg` directly into the virtualenv if you want, then you won't have to hack the PIL build script.  Here's what I did:

```
% mkvirtualenv foo
(foo)% cdvirtualenv
(foo)% lftpget http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
(foo)% tar zxf jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
(foo)% cd jpeg-8c
(foo)% CC="gcc -arch x86_64" ./configure --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV
(foo)% make install
(foo)% cd ..
(foo)% pip install PIL
(foo)% python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _imaging
>>> _imaging
<module '_imaging' from '/Users/nicholas/LMI/foo/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so'>
>>> ^D
```

While `_imaging.so` got built for `i386`, `ppc` and `x86_64` (because that is how Apple's Python was compiled), `libjpeg` was compiled for `x86_64` only because of the flags I gave gcc:

```
(foo)% file lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
lib/libjpeg.8.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
(foo)% file lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so (for architecture i386):    Mach-O bundle i386
lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so (for architecture ppc7400): Mach-O bundle ppc
lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
(foo)% otool -L lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so:
    /Users/nicholas/LMI/foo/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
```

Because `_imaging.so` links to `libjpeg` dynamically, it fails at load time if a dylib is not available with the expected architecture.  I was able to provoke something similar to what you saw by running Python as 32-bit:

```
(foo)% arch -i386 python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nicholas/LMI/foo/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Users/nicholas/LMI/foo/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/nicholas/LMI/foo/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
```

So I'd check that the architectures of Python, PIL and libjpeg are compatible.  It's rather annoying you don't get a better error message though!

Comment: I haven't got back to trying this yet ... sorry about no upvote so far.

Comment: Well, it must not be terribly urgent :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this issue for hours, the only way, was using this package:

http://ethan.tira-thompson.org/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html

to install libjpeg, then PIL will install and work properly from pip and i guess other sources as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkvirtualenv project-env
workon project-env
brew install samueljohn/python/pillow
pip install --upgrade --no-install Pillow
sed -i '.bak' 's?JPEG_ROOT = None?JPEG_ROOT="\/usr\/local\/Cellar\/jpeg\/8c\/"?' $VIRTUAL_ENV/build/Pillow/setup.py
sed -i '.bak' 's/TIFF_ROOT = None/TIFF_ROOT="\/usr\/local\/Cellar\/libtiff\/4.0.3\/"/' $VIRTUAL_ENV/build/Pillow/setup.py
sed -i '.bak' 's/FREETYPE_ROOT = None/FREETYPE_ROOT="\/usr\/local\/Cellar\/freetype\/2.5.0.1\/"/' $VIRTUAL_ENV/build/Pillow/setup.py
sed -i '.bak' 's/LCMS_ROOT = None/LCMS_ROOT="\/usr\/local\/Cellar\/little-cms\/1.19\/"/' $VIRTUAL_ENV/build/Pillow/setup.py
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/build/Pillow/ && python setup.py install
```